# ASUS U47A USB drivers broken

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I recently updated the drivers on my ASUS U47A notebook using ASUS live update. Now, the USB ports simply don't respond.

Running Windows 7 64-bit

Device Statuses:

Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller:

A driver (service) for this device has been disabled.  An alternate driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

Windows did not start a related device driver. To learn more, click the Driver tab and then click Driver Details.

Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller

A driver (service) for this device has been disabled.  An alternate driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

Windows did not start a related device driver. To learn more, click the Driver tab and then click Driver Details.

Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller:

A driver (service) for this device has been disabled.  An alternate driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

Windows did not start a related device driver. To learn more, click the Driver tab and then click Driver Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually trying to troubleshoot this for my sister's u47a right now.

It appears that something from ASUS's LiveUpdate software, possibly (specifically) the Charger+ utility, interferes with the USB 3.0 driver operation.

http://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-16217.html?s=f9d144631af3ff8e84bb6d1a2c79b0ad

We're reverting to a restore point via Windows Backup/Restore right now.

Others have reported success by downloading the updated Charger+ utility from ASUS's site:
http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=111&m=USB%20Charger&os=30&ft=14&f_name=USBChargerPlus_Win7_64_Z211.zip#USBChargerP lus_Win7_64_Z211.zip

Hope this helps.  Otherwise, I'll update with any success we have.

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY! I downgraded to 2.0 (oldest avalable) THEY WORK! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of an interference between the USB mass storage driver (brut) and ASUS USB charger plus (newer versions), otherwise ASUS power4gear program. Uninstall the drivers and the programs, it will work like a charm. Cheers! Viscol.